# CNC Programming - How to mill diagonal edge of a contour (CNC Simulator Pro)?

Tags: cnc

Hope this is the right place to ask.. I'm a Mechatronic Engineering student and am having difficulty programming the mill to cut diagonal edges of contours.  I've worked through [this tutorial](http://cncsimulator.info/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48) which I understand. The problem I'm having is milling around the *outside* of the diagonal edge, not *on* it.  I hope that makes sense. I'm unsure about the tool positioning at the start/end of cut, for example. Can someone explain how to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are describing is called the cutter radius correction. You can activate/deactivate it with the G-codes G40, G41, G42.

These will displace the path with the radius of the active cutter in positive or negative direction.

Comment: So I would mill the contour with the toolpath _on_ the contour (as in the tutorial) but include cutter compensation which will take radius of the cutter into account and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you say